# How to parse raw POST data into array?

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have a raw form-data that look like this:

```
------------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="intro"

O
------------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

T
------------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="apiKey"

98d32fdsa
------------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="method"

/media/add
------------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload_field"; filename="original_filename.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy--
```

(In place of second line of upload_field there are data of this file (invisible here). So my question is:

How to parse above data to have a table:

```
$result['intro']
```

and so on with data inside?

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290132/read-post-request-parameters-properly-in-php-for-request-more-than-1450-b

Comment: @fabrik No, in the question that you linked is very differed. And it's my question too. Please read more carefully.

Comment: I saw that one is your question too. One thing i don't see: the difference. Both question asks to read these values.

Comment: @fabrik In this question I as how to parse raw post data manually. And in the question you linked I ask how to do so that PHP will parse POST request properly on it's own. Do you see the difference now?

Comment: Not really. Good luck, tomaszs.

Comment: @fabrik Thank you, either question I get proper answer it will help a lot. I sure hope that someone knows solution for either of this problems. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$boundary = "------------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy"; // take this from content-type
$rawfields = explode($boundary,$data);
array_pop($rawfields); // drop the last -- piece
foreach ( $rawfields as $id=>$block )
{
    list($mime,$content) = explode("\r\n\r\n",$block,2); // I think it's <cr><lf> by standards, maybe check!
    if ( preg_match('/name="([^"]*)"/i',$mime,$match) )
    {
        $result[$match[1]] = $content;
        // todo: do funky stuff with other fields
    } else {
        $result[] = $content; // just in case...
    }
}
```

presto.

**edit:** you should also trim off the newline from each content block, but `rtrim` will chop more than one newline, so you have to get a little more creative.

Comment: Best exploding the string by new lines then get the first line as boundary, most of the time you will not know the boundry ! - an ragards to cf/nl try standerdizing the new lines `str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"\r\n",$string);`

Comment: this is flawed anyway, should `preg_split("/-+$boundary/",$data)` instead of exploding. replacing newlines doesn't seem wise since you would be altering content as well. But then again the whole setup of parsing this by hand is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

The content-type of the overall document is `multipart`, with the parts being separated by the given boundary.

Each part, or message, within the multipart document is in a standard message format: header lines, followed by a blank line, followed by a sequence of bytes representing the content of that part. Both HTTP and SMTP work like this.

With header lines like `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"`, you have to be careful with the `name` because it could be encoded (think about how to represent an arbitrary value, such as one containing a double quote mark or a newline).

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with a similar problem myself and wrote my own version of mvds's code to also work with binary files. [Here's the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483851/manually-parse-raw-http-data-with-php) for future reference.