# Parse multipart/form-data from PUT request

Tags: php, rest

I'm in the midst of writing a RESTful API, but sadly PHP doesn't have much built-in support for the PUT method.

Does anyone know of a script/library that would parse multipart/form-data in PHP?

Comment: If you've [set up PUT handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) correctly, [here's a hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5488449/1122351).

Comment: Doesn't look like that solution will work with requests containing binary data, as I don't think preg_match is binary safe. I can try it out later tonight, though

Comment: PCRE functions *should* be binary safe.

Comment: Well it looks like I'll have to write my own, as that hack reads the whole input into memory which isn't a good idea if people are uploading huge files heh. I'll comment back if/when I finish the parser.

Answer (score -4):

You can use  [parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $vars)](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php) to access PUT data

Comment: that won't parse multipart/form-data, though. just a query string :(