# Get PATCH request data in PHP

Tags: php, rest

I need to make a `PATCH` request to a PHP application.

How can I get the data from that `PATCH` request inside that application?

If I had to do it with a `POST`, it would just be a simple access to the global `$_POST` variable.

Comment: use $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] for get type of requests.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can get data with [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect2-wrappers.php-unknown-unknown-descriptiop) stream wrapper:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Also make sure your web server supports PATCH requests, some are configured to respond only to GET and POST.

Comment: but how to get use that data as simple like `$_GET or $_POST` ..... it is returning some weird string

Comment: @santosh It's not that simple. You should also check Content-Type request header and decide what to do with this string. It can be JSON, base64 encoded file or urlencoded query string.

Answer (score 34):

I know that this has been solved, but for anyone who was hoping for an answer like

```
$_PATCH["name"];
```

there is a way to do that:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $_PATCH);
```

then you can access it like `$_GET["something"]` and `$_POST["something"]` just do

```
$_PATCH["something"]
```

hope that helped someone :)

Comment: Wait, that doesn't work. I get keys something like `------WebKitFormBoundaryDBQQ4THK5a0cbY20
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name`

Comment: Alright, I just realized this will probably not work correctly in PHP versions < 7

Comment: Not even working in `PHP 7.2.34` getting same `----------------------------541429037887217943792898
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "key"`

Comment: I don't think [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) can parse `multipart/form-data`.  That's why you get boundary strings.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the above has worked for me in PHP 5.6, here's a solution that actually did.

I used [this parse_raw_http_request($data) function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5488449/5560928) by [Christof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/682583/christof).

And here's the code:

```
$_PATCH = [];
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $_PATCH);
parse_raw_http_request($_PATCH);

// From now on, the $_PATCH variable keeps all request arguments as well,
// and they're accessible under approprate keys like $_PATCH['yourKey']
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using : `PHP 7.4`

```
function patchMethod(){
      parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $_PATCH);
              $body=[];
                if (is_array($_PATCH)) {
                   foreach ($_PATCH as $key => $value) {
                    $body[$key] = $value;
                }  
                   
                }
            return $body;    
               
}
```

Answer (score -7):

You have `$_REQUEST` superglobal containing all data we can get regardless the HTTP method used (`GET`, `POST`, `PATCH`, `PUT`)

Comment: No, you don't: `An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.`