# Getting Image/File Data From WebKitFormBoundary PHP

Tags: php, image, forms

I am uploading a file via ajax, an image specifically, and in my upload I am getting this information on the php server:

------WebKitFormBoundaryVuxuxnms21f4i1ZX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG

IHDR,,y}�u IDATx^L�ɓdו�w|v�y�̈���b 8�ɪbUuw���h�Lfj-d2�i!3md���i�fZ���Z&�ꮪ&   �C�������~��"�4gdF�?��s�{�w�sn�ٳ�A�<�Ͽ?��{��o���l4���G�Ջ��'q���x��ftzk�/w���D�������r�l�G�Q���fԪ�hԇ�Z����N7v�:����k����[�뱹�����vkQ���kFt[Q/����lT��x��k���Տ~��V�����N7�v{Q.բT*G�
------WebKitFormBoundaryVuxuxnms21f4i1ZX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

image
------WebKitFormBoundaryVuxuxnms21f4i1ZX--

I know the charaters inside are the image/file being uploaded, but how do I parse the WebKitFormBoundary to only get the file data?

Comment: Why would you want to “parse” anything yourself for a file upload? PHP does that for you automatically (when you use the right format for your upload) … http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: You should be able to receive uploaded file at server using $_FILE global variable of PHP. Once you got the file in it, you can move it to any location.

The data you see above is basically header information + bytes for image file uploaded. Together they form a file. If you remove WebKitFormBoundary data, its just bytes and you wont be able to open it.

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483851/manually-parse-raw-multipart-form-data-data-with-php

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem, and fix it changing request method to 'POST', i hope this help!

Comment: He must be using POST already as you can not send binary data with GET