# Retrieve data from file_get_contents('php://input');

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I am using  `file_get_contents('php://input')` function. How can I convert below data into array?

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="accessKey"

test12313
-----------------------------2154836642318
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

test123
-----------------------------2154836642318--
```

Comment: Into what array? Just to split try [`preg_split('/^(?!\A)(?=Content-Disposition:)/m', $str);`](https://eval.in/844914)

Comment: I'm confused. Is this supposed to be a standard `multipart/form-data` request? If it is, why do you need to replicate PHP's builtin parser? If it isn't, what's the exact difference?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found by knowing what to ask:

[Manually parse raw HTTP data with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483851/manually-parse-raw-http-data-with-php)

You may be able to get away with using PHP's parse_str function, but there is discussion of a custom solution and links to it when you follow my link.