# How can I parse multipart/form-data from an HTTP PUT request into an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, http, put

I'm trying to write a REST API in PHP from the ground up for my website, partly as a learning exercise, partly to develop a codebase that I can reference later in case I forget how something works.

To my dismay, I've discovered that PHP has no $_PUT superglobal.

Remembering that Laravel makes GET/PUT/POST/DELETE distinctions, I figured Laravel must have code to handle HTTP PUT requests correcly, but no, in fact, it depends on a hidden form field with the value "_PUT" to specify the action to take.

**Without the need to process files, is there any way to take multipart/form-data and parse it into an associative array in a similar fashion to $_POST, such that it is foreach iterable?**

Here is what I tried and it simply doesn't work. I'm not understanding what the extra data is that is sent, must be related to the PHP session?

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_PUT);
foreach ($_PUT as $key => $value)
{
    unset($_PUT[$key]);
    $_PUT[str_replace('amp;', '', $key)] = $value;
}
$_REQUEST = array_merge($_REQUEST, $_PUT);
foreach($_PUT as $key=>$value){
    $ani->state[$key]['value'] = $value;
}
```

What I end up getting out of this looks like this: (I am pretty sure I can beat this into what I want, but I don't think what I come up with is going to be robust enough to trust not to break all the time.)

[image: What the server sees in the array after parsing php's stdin]

So as not to anger anyone, the code I'm using came directly from here: https://joshtronic.com/2014/06/01/how-to-process-put-requests-with-php/

I tried to spin my own, which ended up looking very similar to his, minus merging the body back into the request, which I still don't completely understand the purpose of.

Comment: Maybe here is a similar question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5488449/1461181

Comment: @odan Thank you, but this ended up not being what I needed. I found a solution and will post an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is now simply to not use multipart/form-data and instead use application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I don't know if this decision will haunt me later on down the road but it solves my problem for now. I can still use this for my API as in JavaScript I can specify the content type as such:

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

I'd be very interested in knowing why PHP doesn't add a $_PUT superglobal?

Comment: PUT is meant as a method for "uploading" stuff to a particular URI, or overwriting what is already in that URI. POST, on the other hand, is a way of submitting data RELATED to a given URI.  Read more: [PUT method support](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php)

Comment: @odan Right, 'overwriting' is essentially what I am doing. I see POST as creating the initial record or adding new data to it. Never overwriting existing data. Am I missing something? If my logic doesn't make sense here, I'm definitely open to revising it. I'm completely new to this.