# How can I make this cURL request correct? PHP cURL

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl, weasyprint

I`m using weasyprint by aquavitae for generating PDFs for my Laravel application via cURL

```
curl -X POST \
-H Content-Type:text/html \
-T ./test.html http://127.0.0.1:5001/pdf?filename=test.pdf \
-o test.pdf
```

This is an example of cURL request to a weasyprint which gives me a good responce, but when u try to do this in my PHP:

```
    $path_to_file = 'd:/index.html';
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array(
        "Content-Type:text/html"
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.99.100:5001/pdf');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
            'datafile' => curl_file_create($path_to_file , mime_content_type($path_to_file), basename($path_to_file))
        ]
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I get my responce as a line and when I want to responce it to a browser or into a file I get some information about HTML file I sent:
[PDF file I get with PHP cURL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsP1r.png)

tho my HTML file contains only

```
<h1>hello world</h1>
```

I can see something like that when I use Postman too.
I think that there`s some difference beetwen how I send file with CMD cURL and PHP cURL.
Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: If you need any additional information for solving this problem then just tell me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually parse raw multipart/form-data data with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483851/manually-parse-raw-multipart-form-data-data-with-php)

Comment: Looks like you are getting a multipart response, so check the mentioned duplicate for ways to parse this into something more usable.